# Custom type won't let access the object properties

Tags: typescript, types

I created a custom type with an object and a primitive type. in one place I want to check whether my value contains the object property or not. below are my types

```
export type FileTypePrimitive = string | null;

export type FileType = { name: string; url: string };

export type GenratedKey = FileType| FileTypePrimitive;
```

Inhere I want to check that `keysToSend` contains `name` or `url` properties.

```
const keysToSend = genratedFileKeys() // return GenratedKey Type
const url = keysToSend.name ? keysToSend.url : keysToSend; // throws error Property 
// 'name' does not exist on type 'string | FileType'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` operator to determine whether `keysToSend` belongs to one of two primitive types being defined as `FileTypePrimitive`. If it doesn't then TypeScript will infer that it is `FileType`:

```
const url = typeof keysToSend === "string" || keysToSend === null ? keysToSend : keysToSend.url;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUzAJwIZQQEwGIEsA2CA0ggJ4QBcMAFAJQwC8AfDAOJJoaYmmM33MYAWXQALAHRowmEAFs6MFgAZxAVhgB%20GgG8wqWQioAiVEYA0MAK7J8xgEZGAvvWPRkuMHCMBuALAAoAKhSAAcEGDxCABVQhAAFd1lcKFwAN3CGGDcPOBgAHxgwS3x8P0D-YLCIggQYqsztQv1DLKh3T28rGypszxhHMqDYtg50LB4%20SNrhgqm6%20MTktIRB-0JYAGsyCCiQAGUkTCp2FDHuMj5EU64pngg6MtBIWGt8PkqEEAAzGC3yXYO0kYDEyRl6XnyBT%20O32h2BmSKJU0v22ALhVGhaOk4leqyeEBAhHE%20BAcGor1o3iAA)

Typically, you would use the `in` operator but unfortunately it doesn't work on unions of primitive types ([Typescript 4.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#stricter-checks-for-the-in-operator))

Comment: `Property 'url' does not exist on type 'string | EasementFileType'.` im getting this error.is there any way to check keysToSend contains `name` property and if that exist return``keysToSend.url`

Comment: @NicoleZ there was no `EasementFileType` in your question, can you paste a link to Typescript playground or edit your question?

Comment: Sorry it's supposed to be a `FileType`

Comment: @NicoleZ have you seen the playground I pasted? What's the difference between it and your code?

Comment: it's exact same thing but throws an error in my code base.I think the issue is in the transpiler

Answer (score 1):

it's given you that error because the variable keysToSend may be a string so it will not have the property name or url inside of it. you should check the variable type before you access the properties inside of it.

```
const url = typeof keysToSend === "string" ||keysToSend == null ? keysToSend : keysToSend.url;
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUzAJwIZQQEwGIEsA2CA0ggJ4QBcMAFAJQwC8AfDAOJJoaYmmM33MYAWXQALAHRowmEAFs6MFgAZxAVhgB+GgG8wqWQioAiVEYA0MAK7J8xgEZGAvvWPRkuMHCMBuALAAoAKhSAAcEGDxCABVQhAAFd1lcKFwAN3CGGDcPOBgAHxgwS3x8P0D-YLCIggQYqsztQv1DLKh3T28rGypszxhHMqDYtg50LB4+SNrhgqm6+MTktIRB-0JYAGsyCCiQAGUkTCp2FDHuMj5EU64pngg6MtBIWGt8PkqEEAAzGC3yXYO0kYDEyRl6Xhgml+2wBhxgVD+O32h3Er1WTwgIEI4nwIDg1FetG8QA - you will get `Object is possibly 'null'.`

Comment: sorry about that i did test it in vscode and it did not show me that error it's probably because of my tsconfig.